# 8-20 characters, but no spaces allowed anywhere in HTML5 validation

Tags: regex, html, validation

I am trying to restrict space entry in html5 validation.
I tried with

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\*\!\\?\(\)]{8,20}$
```

and

```
^[^-\s]{8,20}$.
```

Problem is its restricting at if I try with only space. If after space I enter anything other than space it allows space at starting also.

I want that no white space should be allowed.

Comment: Second should work... Can you provide a fiddle, what're you doing?

Answer (score 2):

You may try `^\S{8,20}$` which is 8 to 20 non whitespace char.

Comment: After entering 1 or more space(s) but its anything if after space(s). I have to restrict space(s) through out entry.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the meaning of your comment @SaurabhKumarVaidya could you, please, rephrase it? :)

Comment: I want to use html5 validation to validate one text field. In that text field there must not be any space allowed. not before, not in middle and not at last.

Comment: Why character class used? Is not `^\S{8,20}$` same?

Comment: I mean the same thing in this way. Above expression is only working if I am trying to enter only spaces. so string with one or more white space is restricted. Now if after one or more white space if I am entering any other character then its allowing. Even if I am trying spaces then characters then spaces then expression can't restrict submit. My requirement is in text box any space must not be allowed anywhere. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @SaurabhKumarVaidya take a look at the live test [here](https://regex101.com/r/aI0bN4/4) and tell me what's wrong with my solution :)  @ vp_arth you're right

Comment: Great @SaurabhKumarVaidya you may then consider to accept the answer and upvote it if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="yourfile" method="yourmethod">
  Input: <input type="text" name="field" pattern="^\S{8,20}" title="non space string">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need the `$` at the end or the user will be able to enter `qmsldkjf   sdf`

Comment: not needed. it is working fine here, with every situation: "__" means blank space "_xxxx_xxx_xxx_" or "xxxx_xxxx", or "xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx", and many others.